# How to upload a file in angular

Tags: angular, file-upload

I am new to Angular CLI and I want to create a file-uploader. In my case I need to store the files in a folder of the app, not outside of it. I looked at the web, but I can't find any info. To be accurate, I want to store them in the assets folder `assets/media`
 How do I do that?

Comment: If you want your angular app to be able to upload file, you'll need a backend server, handling that request and writing files on disk.

Answer (score 0):

I have something like this:
**html**

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<input type="file" accept=".pdf, .txt" #file placeholder="Choose file" (change)="uploadFile(file.files)" style="display:none;">
<button style="width: 350px" type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="file.click()">Dodaj plik</button>
```

**js**

```
public uploadFile = (files) => {
if (files.length === 0) {
  return;
}
let fileToUpload = <File>files[0];
const formData = new FormData();

formData.append('file', fileToUpload, fileToUpload.name);
this._http.post(this.baseURL + "item/addFile/", formData, { reportProgress: true, observe: 'events' })  
.subscribe(event => {
```

**c#**

```
  [HttpPost, DisableRequestSizeLimit]
    [Route("/item/addFile")]
    public IActionResult Upload()
    {
        try
        {
            var file = Request.Form.Files[0];
            var folderName = Path.Combine("Resources", "Images");
            var pathToSave = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), folderName);
            if (file.Length > 0)
            {
                var fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');
                var fullPath = Path.Combine(pathToSave, fileName);
                var dbPath = Path.Combine(folderName, fileName);
                using (var stream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    file.CopyTo(stream);
                }
                //save to db
                return Ok(new { dbPath });
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(500, $"Internal server error: {ex}");
        }
    }
```